# DataGrid Unselected row appear as selected

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, styles, selection

I have a WPF DataGrid that is based on a style with the trigger:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="DataGridCellStyle">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                    Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**A short description of the problem**: In one case, after changing the selection, the previews not selected row is still marked with Blue and appear as it is selected.

**And more detailed:**
When I'm selecting row X ,  row X is colored with blue.
 When I'm selecting a different row the color in row X changes back to default as it should.

Except for one case:
1.  I'm standing on row X and it is selected. 
2.  I'm swapping it's place with row Y (from code) .
3.  Row X is now still selected after the swap.
4.  I'm going to a different row , The new row is selected , **row X is not selected anymore but it's background is still Blue.**

I'm not sure it can add any extra information, but I'm adding the relevant part of the code of the swapping:
*_commands is binded to the ItemsSource of the dataGrid

```
            Command tmp = _commands[indx1];
        _commands[indx1] = _commands[indx2];
        _commands[indx2] = tmp;
        Commands[indx + 1].IsSelected = true;
        Commands[indx].IsSelected = false;


        private ObservableCollection<CustomCommand> _commands = new ObservableCollection<CustomCommand>();
    public ObservableCollection<CustomCommand> Commands
    {
        get
        {
            return _commands;
        }
        set
        {
            _commands = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Commands");
        }
    }
```

One more thing - This happens only in some of the computers and in others it behaves as expected and the color is set back to default.

Thanks,
Dana.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, I've added an opposite trigger When IsSelected=false:

```
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected"  Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                            </Trigger>
```